# Left aligned image in iPhone navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

currently I'm doing

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

to set an image in the navigation bar. This way it is centered automatically.
Is there any way to have it left aligned ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I've done it:

```
- (void)addLogoLeftButtonBarItem {
    UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyLogo.png"];
    if (logoImage == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Can't open logo image");
    }

    UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];

    UIBarButtonItem *logoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logoImageView];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:logoItem animated:NO];

    [logoItem release];
    [logoImageView release];
}
```

Comment: Great! With setting the `frame` of the `UIImageView` you can also position it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `UIView` as the `titleView`, then put the image view as a subview of that `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add the image view as a subview of the navigation bar and postion it wherever you want.